# Amazon Dynamodb Exception error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

when we are calling dynamodb with http rest api it is giving this error

Can i know what is the problem? what are all the required things we need to append in the dynamodb url??

http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?aws_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&aws_secret_access_key=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Do we need to append anything more parameters with this url please let me know??
**http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingJSON.html#JSONMajorExample**

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is in the same link

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MakingHTTPRequests.html

> If you don't use one of the AWS SDKs, you can perform Amazon DynamoDB operations over HTTP using the POST request method. The POST method requires you to specify the operation in the header of the request and provide the data for the operation in JSON format in the body of the request.

You need to make POST request with all the required parameters mentioned in that page.